# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between "in a job interview", on a job interview" and "at a job interview"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20job%20interview%2Con%20a%20job%20interview%2Cat%20a%20job%20interview&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20job%20interview%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20job%20interview%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20job%20interview%3B%2Cc0), they are all common, except *in a job interview* is even more so. I wonder if there is any nuance of meaning between the three. For example:

> I am really afraid of screwing up **in a job interview**.
>
> I am really afraid of screwing up **on a job interview**.
>
> I am really afraid of screwing up **at a job interview**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough, I would say that there was no difference in meaning between the three examples that you gave, though in slightly different circumstances there are indeed minor differences:

`I am in a job interview` implies that the interview is actively taking place.

`I am on a job interview today` implies that the narrator is a about to take part in an interview, but it hasn't started yet, and they may not even have left for it.

`I am at a job interview` also implies that the narrator is about to have an interview, but also that they have arrived at the location.